# Vector span proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5$ be vectors in $\Bbb R^4$

I'm trying to show that the set (call it set $A$) $\{c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5\}$ spans $\Bbb R^4$ if and only if the set (say, set $B$) of vectors

$\{c_1+c_2,c_2+c_3,c_3+c_4,c_4+c_5,c_5+c_1\}$ spans $\Bbb R^4$

I tried a proof by contradiction to show that there can't exist a vector $b$ that is formed by a linear combination of vectors from $B$ but not from $A$, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Am I messing something up somewhere/is there something I could be doing differently, possibly with matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$ (c_1 + c_2) = (c_1) + (c_2)$

$ (c_1) = \frac {1}{2} \left[ (c_1 + c_2) - (c_2+c_3)+(c_3+c_4) - (c_4+c_5) + (c_5 + c_1)\right]$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure how that's supposed to help. Could you elaborate a bit further, please?

Comment: @user1903336 Can you show that $Span B \subset Span A$ using the first equation (and it's cyclic versions)? Similarly show that $Span A \subset Span B$ using the second equation. Hence conclude that $Span A = Span B$.

Comment: My fundamentals are very fuzzy, sorry. Do you mind explaining yourself a bit more?

Comment: If $b \in Span B$, then $b = \sum b_i ( c_i + c_{i+1})$ (where $c_6 = c_1)$ for some coefficients $b_i$. Then, $b = \sum (b_i + b_{i-1} )c_i$ shows that $b \in Span A$. Thus, $Span B \subset Span A$. Do the second statement in a similar way.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, but I'm having trouble understanding how b=∑(bi+bi−1)ci shows that b∈ Span A. Could you explain why this is so?

Comment: What does it mean for a vector to be in the Span of A?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having just a bit of trouble again. I think I am starting to see what you're getting at. Was the hard part of the thinking trying to figure out how to rearrange the second statement's equation? Is that where your hint comes in? If not, how could I show the reverse statement, then? And if so, isn't there a simpler method?

Comment: The hard part would be finding the equations stated in the hint. The rewrite should be obvious, by just expanding and combining terms.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I can work my way through this proof now. I appreciate your help -- voted and accepted. Afraid I can't do more than that! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually prove something stronger, that A and B always generate the same vector space, by showing that every vector in A can be written as a linear combination of vectors in B, and every vector in B is a linear combination of vectors in A.

Comment: Can you explain why that would work/how I would go about doing that?